# Add the log4J libary to build path failed?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

I am using eclipse as my ide. I want to add log4j to the build path. Therefore I downloaded the zip file from the log4j site. In fact I have my libary as referenced lib, but the logger isn`t recognized by the ide... [image]

I appreaciate your answer!!!

PS.: The import i use is:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Comment: Are you sure about your import? Looks like you have (also) imported `java.util.logging.Logger` since `log.info` is recognized but not `log.error`

Comment: yeah you are right... but i just deleted it;) I think it came when i auto imported the libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click project -> BuidPath -> Configure Build Path

Select library tab
Use add jars or add external jars to include the jar in your project class path.

Hope it helps ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have a zip file as a referenced library and not the actual log4j jar file.

Unzip your file and extract the jar out of it and place it in your build path.

Also, you are using log4j version 2 which is still in alpha and NOT compatible with log4j 1.x

You need [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)